# Debounce @HostListener event

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm implementing a simple infinite-scroll directive in Angular2.
I'm using `@HostListener('window:scroll')` to get the scroll event and parsing the data from the `$target`.

The question is, for every scroll event, everything will be checked once again with no need.

I checked the ionic `infinite-scroll` directive for inspiration but they don't use `@HostListener`, they need a more granular control, I guess.

I ended up on this issue while searching https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248 but couldn't find any way to do what I want.

I think if I create an Observable, subscribe to it with debounce and push (next) items to it, I will reach the behaviour I want, but I'm not being able to do that.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I would leverage debounce method decorator like:

```typescript
export function debounce(delay: number = 300): MethodDecorator {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const timeoutKey = Symbol();

    const original = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function (...args) {
      clearTimeout(this[timeoutKey]);
      this[timeoutKey] = setTimeout(() => original.apply(this, args), delay);
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

and use it as follows:

```typescript
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])  
@debounce() 
scroll(event) {
  ...
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/5CI3cpslGW8sPv09ojxi?open=app%2Fdebounce.decorator.ts)**

Comment: Thanks, worked perfecly. Now just for knowledge purposes, how can I put it in a separate file?

Comment: well I know its too late, but for reference i have implemented the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-debounce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdebounce-example%2Fdebounce-example.component.html

Answer (score 13):

I really like [@yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui)'s solution and I updated a lot of code to use it. However, I think it contains a bug. In the original code, there is only one `timeout` per *class* but in practice one is needed per *instance*.

In Angular terms, this means that if the component in which `@debounce()` is used is instantiated multiple times in a container, every instantiation will `cancelTimeout` the previous instantiation and only the last will fire.

I propose this slight variant to eliminate this trouble:

```js
export function debounce(delay: number = 300): MethodDecorator {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {

    const original = descriptor.value;
    const key = `__timeout__${propertyKey}`;

    descriptor.value = function (...args) {
      clearTimeout(this[key]);
      this[key] = setTimeout(() => original.apply(this, args), delay);
    };

    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

Of course, it is possible to be more sophisticated about disambiguating the synthetic `__timeout__` property.

Comment: @A.MatíasQuezada you can also use a Symbol I think.

Comment: @LppEdd yes but Symbol is not supported by IE yet and the polyfill has some tricky caveheats (https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#caveats-when-using-symbol-polyfill). Let's update it when they are supported by "the brosers of the internet"!

Answer (score 9):

An RXJS way of doing this can be achieved using [`fromEvent`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent) together with the [`throttleTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/throttletime) operator.

Instead of decorating your event handler with `@HostListener`, you create an observable from the event using `fromEvent` (e.g., in the `ngOnInit` method) and then throttling the emission of events using `throttleTime`.

```js
...
import {fromEvent, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {tap, throttleTime} from 'rxjs/operators';


export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { 

  private eventSub: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventSub = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
      throttleTime(300), // emits once, then ignores subsequent emissions for 300ms, repeat...
      tap(event => this.scroll(event))
    ).subscribe();
  }

  scroll(event) {
    ...
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.eventSub.unsubscribe(); // don't forget to unsubscribe
  }
}
```

One advantage of using RXJS is that you can pass in custom schedulers to the `throttleTime` operator to achieve different behaviours. For example, you can throttle event emission by the animation frame rate (e.g., to throttle the emission of touch events).

```js
import {animationFrameScheduler, ...} from 'rxjs';
...

this.eventSub = fromEvent(window, 'touchmove').pipe(
  throttleTime(0, animationFrameScheduler),
  tap(event => ...)
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use lodash in their project you can use this:

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash-es';
...
@HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll = debounce(() => {
  ...
}, 300);
```

or if you need throttle

```
import { throttle } from 'lodash-es';
...
@HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll = throttle(() => {
  ...
}, 300);
```