# Angular change detection mechanism fires too often

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

In one of my controllers I have :

```
 @HostListener('window:resize')
onResize() {
this.currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

and based on the window Width, I render different views. One of which needs to do some calculations.
But since the change detection mechanism fires too often, this really slows down the app and there's a delay.

How are such situations managed best?

Comment: You can use `Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize').throttleTime(200)...` or `Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize').debounceTime(200)...`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849347/1009922).

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634992/debounce-hostlistener-event

Answer (score 2):

That's not related to Angular change detection, it's the resize event that happens that often

Also `@HostListener()` is currently not a good option to list to events that are emitted that frequently https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248

You can use

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
        .debounceTime(100)
        .subscribe((event) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            this.currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
          });
        });
  });
}
```