# HostListener slow app, checking on every pixel for window resize event

Tags: angular

I use angular4 and @HostListener seems to check or ran on every pixel, in this simple example with windows resize. If I apply this as a directive, the app slows down, as well if we hardcoded into every component. I saw many solutions, but all ends with the same result. I don't know if trying with or applying debounceTime or have as injectable with debounceTime...

Any ideas?

```
    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
      event.target.innerWidth;
    }
```

Comment: Our app has over 200 components :|

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634992/debounce-hostlistener-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debounce @HostListener event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634992/debounce-hostlistener-event)